# Split string of a data frame in new columns

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I need your help, because I got a data frame with a very difficult format. My data frame

```
data <- data.frame(information = c("{u'info1': u'mnfd', u'text': u'exampletext'}","{u'info2': u'332', u'text': u'lalala'}","{u'info1': u'', u'text': u'blub'}"))
```

has the column information (and a few other columns in the real data frame) and looks for example like that

```
##                                    information
## 1 {u'info1': u'mnfd', u'text': u'exampletext'}
## 2       {u'info2': u'332', u'text': u'lalala'}
## 3            {u'info1': u'', u'text': u'blub'}
```

The real data frame has a few thousand rows and the strings are much longer. I would like to add columns which should display the information from the strings. So at the end I would like to have a dataframe looking like that (the string "of_" is added before every columnn name)

```
                                   information of_info1     of_text of_info2
1 {u'info1': u'mnfd', u'text': u'exampletext'}     mnfd exampletext     <NA>
2       {u'info2': u'332', u'text': u'lalala'}     <NA>      lalala      322
3            {u'info1': u'', u'text': u'blub'}                 blub     <NA>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is close to a JSON file, so do a bit of formatting to get it right, and then import via the awesome `jsonlite` package:

```
library(jsonlite)
fromJSON(paste0("[", paste(gsub("(u|)'",'"',data$information), collapse=",\n"), "]"))

#  info1        text info2
#1  mnfd exampletext  <NA>
#2  <NA>      lalala   332
#3              blub  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version with `dplyr` and `stringr`. It should not be too difficult to translate it into base R if you prefer that.

This will break, however, if there are escaped single quotation marks in the fields.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

  data <- data$information %>% str_match_all("u'([^']+)': u'([^']*)'") %>% 
      lapply(function(matches) {
         result <- data.frame(as.list(matches[,3]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
         colnames(result) <- paste0("of_", matches[,2])
         result
      }) %>% bind_rows() %>% bind_cols(data, .)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to DCF format and then read it in using `read.dcf`.  No packages are used.

First we remove the junk giving `s0` and then split it on comma-space giving `s1`.  Then add an empty terminating line between records giving `s2`.  Finally use `read.dcf` to read that in and append it to `data`.

```
s0 <- gsub("[{}]", "", gsub("u'(.*?)'", "\\1", data$information))
s1 <- strsplit(s0, ", ")
s2 <- unlist(lapply(s1, c, ""))
cbind(data, read.dcf(textConnection(s2)))
```

giving:

```
                                   information info1        text info2
1 {u'info1': u'mnfd', u'text': u'exampletext'}  mnfd exampletext  <NA>
2       {u'info2': u'332', u'text': u'lalala'}  <NA>      lalala   332
3            {u'info1': u'', u'text': u'blub'}              blub  <NA>
```

**magrittr**

This could also be expressed as a nested magrittr pipeline like this:

```
library(magrittr)

data %>%
     cbind({.$information %>%
        gsub("u'(.*?)'", "\\1", .) %>%
        gsub("[{}]", "", .) %>%
        strsplit(", ") %>%
        lapply(c, "") %>%
        unlist %>%
        textConnection %>%
        read.dcf
     })
```